# Attempting to add a string to one string list but end up adding a string to TWO string lists.

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class NetworkEntry { 
    private String name;
    private int cost;
    private StringListExt predList;
    private StringListExt succList;

public NetworkEntry(String nameval, int costval, String pred){
    name = nameval;
    cost = costval;
    predList = new StringListExt();
    succList = new StringListExt();
    predList.add(pred);
}
```

So the constructor is supposed to instantiate predList and succList while adding the string, red inside of the predList. However, when I call print to see what's inside predList and succList, pred shows up in both of them.

And StringListExt is just an extension of

```
protected static ArrayList <String> list;


public StringList () {
    list = new ArrayList <String>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use static

```
protected static ArrayList <String> list;
```

If you use static, that means that there will only be one of this variable - shared between all instances in the JVM.

As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects.
>   This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the
>   static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class
>   variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any
>   object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is
>   in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a
>   class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without
>   creating an instance of the class.